# SharePoint Document Library Views are no longer visible

Tags: 2007, web-part, list-view

I created 5 different views in a document library and by accidently I went to the edit page of the library and deleted the default document library webpart. Now I added the same doclib webpart again to the page but it no longer displays the views that I created on the right side view filter toolbar. When I goto the document library settings I do see that views still exist for that List. Any idea how can I bring back the view filter for that webpart?

Thanks

Comment: Which version are you using: 2007 or 2010? You tagged the question for both.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, do you mean you were in edit mode on the list view page of the library (where you said you were on the edit page)?

Comment: Actually this happend in 2007 and Yes I was on the AllItems page of the List.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on SharePoint 2010 you can just edit and unghost the page in SharePoint Designer (see [Mike Smith's blog post](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-2010-missing-view-dropdown.html) about this isse), on 2007 it might be more tricky since you not just closed, bit actually deleted the default web part. [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/bb17bbe1-e30c-40b0-a10d-dfc679bf72b7) on MSDN lists some advice.